# Convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^{1.05}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^{1.05}}$$

In an attempt to not have to memorize so many tests I am trying to work out everything using the geometric series test, integral test, p-series test, comparison test and Leibniz test. I think I can do it, basically I don't want to use the limit comparison test.

Since $\ln n$ is practically one for very large numbers can I say the p series is valid and that this converges according to that?

I tried to make a comparison to a larger function but that is hard to do. Can I also use the geometric series test in a similar fashion where I have an $\ln n$ in the numerator and a $x^n$ in the denominator?

Comment: $\ln n$ is not "practically one" for very large numbers.

Comment: Compared to n it is.

Comment: Oh, you mean the series behaves the same as  $\sum{1\over n^{1.05}}$. To be rigorous:  For any $\alpha>0$, $\ln n <n^\alpha$ for $n$ sufficiently large. This is the key for one method to show your series converges (as Jared suggests below).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the limit comparison test, then you can use comparison with $\ln n<n^{.04}$ for large enough $n$.  You can also use the integral test (integrate by parts).

Here are some more details for the comparison test.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{1.05}}<\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\ln n}{n^{1.05}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{n^{.04}}{n^{1.05}}=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\ln n}{n^{1.05}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1.01}}<\infty$$

where $N$ is large enough so that $\ln n<n^{.04}$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: The integral test looked really hard because I forgot how to do an exponential integration. I don't follow your comparison though.

Comment: +1 @Paul: $\ln n/n^{0.04}$ is bounded (tends to zero as $n\to\infty$). And $\sum_n n^{-1.01}$ converges, so...

Comment: So what? I don't follow. $\frac{1}{n}$ is bounded too.

Comment: @Paul: I've added a bit more detail for the comparison test.

Comment: I don't really follow that comparison, your comparison is recrusive in that the assumption that  it converges is based on the original converging.

Comment: @Jared : I can't follow how does $\ln n<n^{.04}$ helps? on the other hand I can see how would $\frac {\ln n}{n^{.04}} < \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ where $\alpha>1$ help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: use integral comparison test. The function of the type (use integration by parts and the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{a-1}}=0$
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log x dx}{x^a}=\frac{\log x}{(1-a)x^{a-1}}\Bigg|_{1}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{1-a}\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-a}dx=\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}<\infty
$$
where $a>1$. Hence your sum converges too.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
for any positive $a$ and $b$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\ln n)^a}{n^{1+b}}$
converges.

The proof involves
starting with
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln n/n =  0$.

Replacing $n$ with $n^b$ we get
$\lim_{n \to \infty} b\ln n/n^b =  0$,
or
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln n/n^b =  0$.

Raising this to the $a$ power,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln n)^a/n^{ab} =  0$.

Replacing $b$ by $b/a$ we get
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln n)^a/n^{b} =  0$.

Replacing $b$ by $b/2$ we get
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\ln n)^a/n^{b/2} =  0$.

The next result needed is that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{1+b/2}}$
converges.

Multiplying the terms of the last two,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\ln n)^a}{n^{1+b}}$
converges.